# Inkscape: fill non-delimited area with colour

Tags: inkscape, vector, fill

I'm very new to Inkscape and I'm trying to edit the SVG schematic of a brain which I've attached below. The outlines consist of separate brushstrokes. I would like to fill some of the gyri with red, so I would like to fill an area with red that is partially delimited by the outlines, but not everywhere. I've also attached a low quality example of what I want to achieve.

I think I probably have to convert some brushstrokes to paths and then connect nodes at the end of the paths to create the borders that aren't defined by brushstrokes? But I haven't managed to figure out how.

original image: https://svgur.com/s/T9S

coloured in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrJm4.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

1. Select and delete all the grey filled objects.
2. Draw some black lines with the Draw Freehand (Pencil) tool to make fully enclosed (or bounded) areas.

[image]

3. Use the Fill Bounded Areas tool (aka the Bucket Fill tool) to fill the enclosed area with colour. You may have to zoom in a bit to get this to work well. There are also Tool Controls for this tool - what worked for me was Tolerance 64, Grow/Shrink by 0.5px
4. Select the filled shape created, and hit the *Lower Selection to Bottom* button to send it to the bottom of the object stack.

If you don't want these extra lines you made in step 2, then you can just select them and delete them afterwards.

[image]